# generating out_table in R

Tags: r, phyloseq

How can I neatly and easy generate an out_table. 
I classified groups with `cutree()` of a `hclust()` object. My samples are diet protocols. In my `otu_table`, the diets shouöd be the samples and the taxa should be the groups.

example

```
#base data for the groups
base <- data.frame(row.names = c("apple","bread","banana","orange juice"),calories=c(45,87,97,30),Mg=c(45,23,89,64))

 calories Mg
apple              45 45
bread              87 23
banana             97 89
orange juice       30 64

base_dist <- dist(base)
h_base <- hclust(base_dist,method="average")
cut_base <- cutree(h_base,h=0.5)

otu_diets <- mutate(base,cluster = cut_base)##adding cluster info to df

#samples
diet1 <- data.frame(row.names = c(" red apple","banana","bread","strawberry"),calories=c(45,56,72,32),Pt=c(0,23,56,45))

diet2 <- data.frame(row.names = c("banana","bread","orange juice","apple"),calories=c(45,56,75,22),Pt=c(89,23,56,45))
```

As you can see, in the diet protocols some food is called differently than in the `base` data.frame. Also there is food in the diet protocols that does  not occur in `base`. I want the `otu_table` to look like this

```
otu <- data.frame(row.names = c("diet1","diet2"),group1=c(1,1),group2=c(1,1),group3=c(1,1),group4=c(0,1))
otu <- otu_table(otu)

group1 group2 group3 group4
diet1      1      1      1      0
diet2      1      1      1      1
```

So the `otu_table` classifies how many foods of the respective diet are in the groups. In real life I have a lot of diet protocols and many groups so I can´t do it manually like in the above example.